# Comsuming RESTful service in javascript

Tags: json, wcf, rest, jsonp

I am trying to consume my newly setup RESTful WCF service, located at

[http://196.34.92.60/api/api/v1/public.svc/getoperators]

I accessed it using some third party tools, which I grabbed from

http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/restclient-tool/

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restclient/

and my results look like I expected:

```
{
   "Results":
   [
       "golden arrow",
       "jammie",
       "myciti"
   ]
}
```

All fine and well.  When I just type the url into my web browser, the response is

```
<ResultList xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Developer_Portal"xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Results xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"><a:string>golden arrow</a:string><a:string>jammie</a:string><a:string>myciti</a:string></Results></ResultList>
```

Not what I expected, but I assumed  this was normal, and tried to comsume service in Javascript (here is fiddle)

http://jsfiddle.net/JmTe4/11/

It responds with an error.  At this point I'm stumped: what do I need to do to get the desired response in javascript?

Comment: You can only call the domain the JS came from, to prevent XSS. E.g. script located on jsfiddle.net will not be allowed to call your domain/ip.

Comment: Two things: 1) Same Origin Policy, 2) "Accepts" request header tells the server what format it should return.

Comment: I just tried the same javascript from a local html page, and added the line 
Accepts: "application/json",
to the ajax request on line 16. This didn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the server webconfig. I had to add

```
<binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
```

Thanks for your suggestions guys, they probably solved some other problems I would have come across anyway. :)

Comment: https://github.com/jpillora/jquery.rest#basic-usage might make your life abit easier

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things.  Some of which were already mentioned by other members.

1. AJAX calls via XMLHttpRequest will not work across domains.  In other words, your AJAX code cannot call 196.34.92.60 from jsfiddle.net.  They are different domains.
2. Your browser is returning XML since it is sending "Accepts: text\html" as a header.  jQuery will resolve this issue as it uses application\json in the request (unless you specify otherwise).

So issue 2 is already fixed.  Issue 1 can be resolved by using JSONP.  You should just need to add ?callback=? to the end of your url.  However, read through the documentation on jQuery's site for a full overview.

Go to this URL and search the page for "JSONP" http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: If you check the fiddle, I've already used dataType: "jsonp", which automatically adds ?callback=? ... this should solve cross domain problem?

Comment: You can use jsonp , only if its supported by server

Comment: If I check the we console it says syntaxerror:invalid label followed by a hyperlink "getoperarors:1" that contains the elusive response I am looking for.  So the correct data is returning, but with some error.

Comment: After some browsing I think it's the server that doesn't support the jsonp callback.  I'll edit the service and get back to say if it worked :)